# Get last balance sign change in (My)SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Transaction table that records every amount *added to* or *subtracted from* the balance of a Customer, with the new balance:

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| id | customerId | timestamp  | amount | balance |
+----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
|  1 |          1 | 1000000001 |     10 |      10 |
|  2 |          1 | 1000000002 |    -20 |     -10 |
|  3 |          1 | 1000000003 |    -10 |     -20 |
|  4 |          2 | 1000000004 |     -5 |      -5 |
|  5 |          2 | 1000000005 |     -5 |     -10 |
|  6 |          2 | 1000000006 |     10 |       0 |
|  7 |          3 | 1000000007 |     -5 |      -5 |
|  8 |          3 | 1000000008 |     10 |       5 |
|  9 |          3 | 1000000009 |     10 |      15 |
| 10 |          4 | 1000000010 |      5 |       5 |
+----+------------+------------+--------+---------+
```

The Customer table stores the current balance, and looks like:

```
+----+---------+
| id | balance |
+----+---------+
|  1 |     -20 |
|  2 |       0 |
|  3 |      15 |
|  4 |       5 |
+----+---------+
```

I would like to add a `balanceSignSince` column, that would store the timestamp at which the balance sign last changed. Transitioning to and from *positive*, *negative*, or *zero* counts as a balance change.

After the update, based on the above data, the Customer table should contain:

```
+----+---------+------------------+
| id | balance | balanceSignSince |
+----+---------+------------------+
|  1 |     -20 |       1000000002 |
|  2 |       0 |       1000000006 |
|  3 |      15 |       1000000008 |
|  4 |       5 |       1000000010 |
+----+---------+------------------+
```

**How can I write a SQL query that updates every Customer with the last time the balance sign changed, based on the Transaction table?**

I suspect I can't do this without a quite complex stored procedure, but am curious to see if any clever ideas come up.

Comment: Why would customer 1 have a value of  `1000000002` and not `1000000003`?

Comment: Because this is when the balance sign transitioned to negative. The next transaction didn't affect the sign of the balance.

Comment: forget it, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a simulated rank() function.

```
select customerId, min(tstamp) from
(
select tstamp,
       if (@cust = customerId and sign(@bal) = sign(balance), @rn := @rn,
           if (@cust = customerId and sign(@bal) <> sign(balance), @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := 0)) as rn,
       @cust := customerId as customerId, @bal := balance as balance
from
      (select @rn := 0) x,
      (select id, @cust := customerId as customerId, tstamp, amount, @bal := balance as balance 
       from trans order by customerId, tstamp desc) y
) z
where rn = 0
group by customerId;
```

Check it: http://rextester.com/XJVKK61181

This script returns a table like this:

```
+------------+----+------------+---------+
| tstamp     | rn | customerId | balance |
+------------+----+------------+---------+
| 1000000003 | 0  | 1          | -20     |
| 1000000002 | 0  | 1          | -10     |
| 1000000001 | 1  | 1          | 10      |
| 1000000006 | 0  | 2          | 0       |
| 1000000005 | 2  | 2          | -10     |
| 1000000004 | 2  | 2          | -5      |
| 1000000009 | 0  | 3          | 15      |
| 1000000008 | 2  | 3          | 5       |
| 1000000007 | 3  | 3          | -5      |
| 1000000010 | 0  | 4          | 5       |
+------------+----+------------+---------+
```

Then selecting min(timestamp) of files where rn = 0:

```
+------------+-------------+
| customerId | min(tstamp) |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 1000000002  |
+------------+-------------+
| 2          | 1000000006  |
+------------+-------------+
| 3          | 1000000009  |
+------------+-------------+
| 4          | 1000000010  |
+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer with the restriction that this needs to work on the existing data**

The following query should work for most cases, there is still an issue with customers having only a single transaction or no sign change. As this is a one time update, I would run the query below and then do a simple update for all users not having a timestamp set, for them it's going to be the timestamp of the first transaction:

```
# Find the smallest timestamp, e.g. the  
# transaction which changed the signum.
SELECT
    p.customerId as customerId,
    MIN(t.timestamp) as balanceSignSince
FROM
    transaction as t,
    (
      # find the latest timestamp having
      # a different sign for each user.
      # Here is the issue with users having
      # only a single transaction or no sign
      # changes.
      SELECT 
        u.customerId as customerId,
        MAX(t.timestamp) as balanceSignSince
      FROM
        transaction as t,
        customer as c,
        (
          # find the timestamp of the very last 
          # transaction for every user.
          SELECT 
            t.customerId as customerId,
            MAX(t.timestamp) as lastTransaction            
          FROM
            transaction as t
          GROUP BY 
            t.customerId
        ) as u
        WHERE
          u.customerId = c.id
          AND u.customerId = t.customerId
          AND SIGN(c.balance) <> SIGN(t.balance)
      GROUP BY
        u.customerId
    ) as p
WHERE 
    p.customerId = t.customerId
    AND p.balanceSignSince < t.timestamp
GROUP BY
    p.customerId;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd0760/13

---

**Original Answer**

This should work to get the timestamp of a sign change:

```
SELECT 
    c.id as id,
    MAX(t.timestamp) as balanceSignSince 
FROM 
    transaction as t, 
    customer as c
WHERE
    t.customerId = c.id
    AND SIGN(t.balance) <> SIGN(c.balance)
```

This needs to be executed before the customer table is updated with the new balance. If you have a trigger on transation:insert you should probably put the above into the query updating the customer table.

Comment: Your solution has something clever, comparing the sign of the latest transaction to the sign of the current customer balance. The problem is, it's not designed to be executed in a trigger, but as a one-off "import" query when adding the `balanceSignSince` column, so it needs to work on existing data in its current form. Subsequent updates to `balanceSignSince` will be performed in the application code.

Comment: I've created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd0760/2) from your solution (adding a missing `GROUP BY`), but unfortunately it doesn't return the appropriate timestamps.

Comment: I updated the answer with the requirement of it being a purely one-time update functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I've preferred @McNets' solution because it is shorter, and works fine even for customers having a single transaction. +1 anyway for you, and thanks for your time!